# How can the mouse in "If You Give A Mouse A Cookie" repeat his actions?

Tags: laura-numeroff, if-you-give-a-mouse-a-cookie

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_You_Give_a_Mouse_a_Cookie):

> A boy gives a cookie to a mouse. The mouse asks for a glass of milk. He then requests a straw (to drink the milk), a mirror (to avoid a milk mustache), nail scissors (to trim his hair in the mirror), and a broom (to sweep up his hair trimmings)

Considering that the whole point of the book (and its sequels) is that the story is a neverending loop, how can the mouse repeat his actions? Shouldn't he get stopped by the trimming his whiskers part? After all, once they're trimmed, they're trimmed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mouse whiskers, like those of male humans, [grow back after having been trimmed or even removed entirely.](http://www.fancymicebreeders.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=4687) So it's possible for the whisker-trimming to take place as part of a never-ending loop: by the time the sequence of events returns to the whisker-trimming stage, the whiskers have grown back enough to be trimmed again.

In reality this would probably take a lot longer than a single day to happen, but the writer is using [artistic licence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license) to truncate the circular series of events into a manageably short narrative.